# Bluetooth Paired But Not Connected

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth, software-update

I was trying to connect my bluetooth headset to my laptop so that I can play music from the build-in speaker and play skype chat from the headset and it won't interfere each other. However, I wasn't able to achieve this goal.

I have a Lenovo W530, running Windows 7 64-bit. I have run Windows update so I believe the drivers are the most current.

When I try to connect my bluetooth headset, my laptop was able to pair with the headset, but it was not able to connect. When I click on the bluetooth icon in the tray, "*Allow a Device to Connect*" is greyed out and I can't click on it.

I go into **Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound**, my headset show up in the list of devices, but it is also greyed out and show "disconnect", and I was not able to connect from there either.

**Is there a way I can solve this issue?**

**Or is there some other free bluetooth software that I can use?**

I tried BlueSoliel, but I ran into couple issue with that too. The first time I was able to connect my headset and use it as desire, but when I restart the program (or restart the computer, I can't really remember), it starts failing. The program says that the headset is connected, but I can not play any sound through the headset, or use the mic on the headset, and my headset is not showing up in **Hardware and Sound** anymore.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: It may be unrelated, but we've had quite a few problems with the bluetooth/wifi drivers with our Lenovo ThinkPads in the past. You mentioned you've run Windows Updates, I would suggest checking Lenovo's site for any specific Bluetooth drivers they have. We tend to use their ThinkVantage update application, "TVSU.exe", for those needs. For several wifi issues on these devices, one solution with connectivity was to uninstall the wifi driver and let the device automatically reinstall it. You can try this if you'd like from the Device Manager.

Comment: @root I don't have issue with wifi though. I tried went into Device Manager, remove the bluetooth drivers, restart the computer and let it install the drivers again, but it was no help. Should I do the same thing with wifi drivers too? I tried typing in TVSU.exe in Run but got an error saying it doesn't exist, should I download it from somewhere?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the wifi drivers, the only reason I mentioned them is because Lenovo ThinkPads often intertwine wifi/bluetooth settings, as per Fn + F5 enabling/disabling ALL radio beacons (both wifi and bluetooth). TVSU stands for "ThinkVantage System Update" and you can download it from [link](http://support.lenovo.com) Lenovo's phone support reps have advised me that some updates that are found in the TVSU client will not properly install if ALL available updates, including optional updates, are not run as well. If you try this, make sure you run them all. Hope this helps